# Interface class in Java

Tags: java

This question may be a little off-topic but I can't really understand why there is no `Interface` class in Java.

Every class defined has its `java.lang.Class` object constructed by JVM. And naturally to me, interfaces should not fall into `Class` objects, but `java.lang.Interface` objects instead. That would make sense, wouldn't it?

I know there is this class assignability thing going on so that a class implementing an interface can be casted to that interface, but wouldn't it be a better idea to call it `Type` instead of `Class`? And then extend `Type` to create `Class` and `Interface`.

I know for sure Java developers won't do anything about it, but I'm just curious.

Comment: What would be the benefit of having separate classes for this?

Comment: Because interface is not a class. That sounds natural for me.

Comment: And that's why there are keywords ``class`` and ``interface``.

Comment: Sure, because it makes a difference from a keyword point-of-view.  But again, what would the benefit be of a separate `Interface` class?

Comment: Because that creates confusion. I think that's fairly enough to at least try questioning the reason there's not ``Interface`` class.

Comment: Interfaces are useless without anything concrete. Implementation class gives it practical behaviour. Thats why it should be Class only.

Comment: Well the same question could be why are interfaces compiled into `*.class` files. Maybe there is answer somewhere in JLS :)...

Comment: Until Java 8 there was no such thing as an instance of Interface.

Comment: I don't know how anyone can answer this question in an objective manner, barring the designers of the language.  This does not seem like a question well suited for SO.

Comment: You want a **class** but want to call it **Interface**?

Comment: @SteveP Would it be better if this question was moved to Programmers SE?

Comment: @wassup If you want people's opinions, perhaps they will be more understanding, but again, this seems like a question solely for the designers of Java...

Comment: @SteveP Okay. So if no one answers this questions, let a moderator move it to Programmers SE.

Comment: @wassup: I see your point now. It kind of implies that there should be `.interface` files also instead of just `.class` files. Right?

Comment: May be decided to have one class for convenience of class loading, but there is still isInterface() method to check.

Comment: Isn't Class.isInstance() sufficient to distinguish between class-or-interface type of one kind and the other?

Comment: @laune But that still does not explain why it's called ``java.lang.Class`` and not e.g. ``java.lang.Type``.

Comment: The `Class` class implements the `Type` interface. Look at the javadoc of its various sub interfaces (and implementing class) to make sense of it all.

Comment: @wassup See [jls-12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2), "Loading of Classes and Interfaces" - *The binary format of a class or interface is normally the class file format described in The Java Virtual Machine Specification, Java SE 7 Edition cited above, but other formats are possible, provided they meet the requirements specified in §13.1. The method defineClass of class ClassLoader may be used to construct Class objects from binary representations in the class file format.*

Answer (score 2):

You are probably right. `Class` not only represents classes and interfaces but also enums, arrays and primitive types. `Type` seems to better describe its purpose. It might also make sense to have derived classes like `AnonymousClass`. Currently some methods such as `getEnclosingConstructor()` work only for certain types of classes.

In fact, designers of C# decided to call their equivalent [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx).

To know exactly why this was done this way, you would have to ask the people who made that decision. My guess is that in Java 1.0 this made more sense, as `Class` was more tied to `.class` file.